# How to mock Discord instance methods inside a listener of a class mocked with jest mock?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, discord, mocking

I have a class using Discord, really having a hard time figuring out how to mock its constructor, instance methods and listeners.

Here is the class `discord.js`

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const env = require('../env');
const {readDb} = require("../db");

let guildMembers = [];
let guild = null;

// setup discord client to listen events
async function setup() {
    try {
        const invites = new Map();

        // Create a new client instance
        const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES] });
        await client.login(env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);

        client.on("ready", async () => {
            // loop over all the guilds
            try {
                guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(env.DISCORD_SERVER_ID);
                guildMembers = await guild.members.cache;
                client.guilds.cache.forEach(async (guild) => {
                    // fetch all Guild Invites
                    const firstInvites = await guild.invites.fetch();
                    // set the key as Guild ID, and create a map which has the invite code, and the number of uses
                    invites.set(guild.id, new Map(firstInvites.map((invite) => [invite.code, invite.uses])));
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Discord ready event error', e);
            }
        });

        client.on('inviteCreate', async invite => {
            try {
                invites.get(invite.guild.id).set(invite.code, invite.uses);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Discord inviteCreate event error', e);
            }
        });

        client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
            try {
                member.guild.invites.fetch().then(async newInvites => {
                    // this is the *existing* invites for the guild
                    const oldInvites = invites.get(member.guild.id);
                    // go through the invites, find the one for which the uses went up
                    const invite = newInvites.find(i => i.uses > oldInvites.get(i.code));
                    if(invite) {
                        if (invite.uses > 1) {
                            // if try to join, invalidate invite and kick the one joined
                            invite.delete().then((member) => {
                            }).catch(console.error);
                            member.kick().then((member) => {
                            }).catch(console.error);
                        } else {
                            // check masterclass invites
                            const masterclass = await readDb.masterclass.fetchMasterclassDiscordChannelRoleByInviteCode(invite.code);
                            if (masterclass) {
                                // join masterclass channel
                                member.roles.add(masterclass.discord_role_id).then(() => {
                                }).catch(console.error);
                            }
                            // join membership channel
                            member.roles.add(env.DISCORD_MEMBERSHIP_ROLE_ID).then(() => {}).catch(console.error);
                            // delete invite after used
                            invite.delete().then((member) => {
                            }).catch(console.error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Discord guildMemberAdd event error', e);
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Discord error', e);
    }
}
```

Here is the test class `discord.test` I have written so far

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const DiscordService = require('../../services/discord');

jest.mock('discord.js');


describe('Discord service', function(){

    it('setup Discord client', async () => {
        const result = await DiscordService.setup();
        expect(Client).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });


});
```

The first test case works but I can't quite figure out how to test the Client constructor with instance methods like **.login** and the listener like **.on("ready", method)**

and how do I reach the method **await client.guilds.cache.get(env.DISCORD_SERVER_ID);** inside .on('ready')...

any help is appreciated.